# Qt QML MenuItem iconSource not show

Tags: qt, qml

I have a very simple setup just to exemplify the problem:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    menuBar:MenuBar{
        Menu{
            id:mainmenu
            title:"&File"
            MenuItem{action: settingsAction}
        }
    }
    Action {
            id: settingsAction
            text: "Settings"
            iconName: "icon-settings"
            iconSource: "qrc:///images/images/cog.png"
        }
    Button{
        text:"Push"
        iconSource: "qrc:///images/images/cog.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

}
```

As you ca see, the button and the menu item has the same url as iconSource.
The button shows the image, but the menu item doesn't.

[screencapture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPAxD.png)

Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Probably related to this Bug: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37083 - When inspected with `qmlscene` at least a *placeholder* for the Icon was shown, while it isn't when running the code normaly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed the problem of yours is a [bug](http://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-37083) that is already know, but as `QtQuick.Controls 1.x` is not maintained any more, I don't know if it will ever be fixed (unless it is a bug in QtGuiApplication?)

As described in the bugreport, you may use [`QApplication`](https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-dev/qapplication.html) instead of `QGuiApplication` in your main to have it shown.

What you are doing wrong?
Nothing. It's all QT's fault.

Comment: Setting `iconName` and `iconSource` is what you want to do if you want to target platforms that support icon themes and platforms that don't. http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html#iconName-prop says: "The image label source as theme name. When an icon from the platform icon theme is found, this takes precedence over iconSource."

Comment: Ok, I never went too deep into the `Controls 1.x`. I will edit my answer accordingly