# How to use Image as iconSource in MenuItem

Tags: qt, qml, menuitem

I want to add icon to my menu item in QML. Only way that works is to assign qt resource url "qrc://..."  to `MenuItem.iconSourse`

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2       
MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Find...")
            iconSource: "qrc:/img/find.png"  // icon show OK
            shortcut:  "Ctrl+F"
        }
```

but i need to get image from plugin resourses. I tried imageprovider, it works well for `Image.sourse` but for `MenuItem` doesn't

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2    
import plugins.spmqml.colorschema 1.0
    ...
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Find...")
                iconSource: "image://provider/find.png" // icon doesn't show
                shortcut:  "Ctrl+F"
            }
```

imageprovider `requestImage` function not even called.

Is any way to load image from plugin to MenuItem?

Comment: When using the qt resource system all paths in qml are relative to where the qrc file lives. Anything outside the resource system should be an absolute file path.

Comment: I would put that in a Row{ Image{}; MenuItem{} } or Column{ Image{}; MenuItem{} } (depends) while concluding there is a problem with QtQuick control MenuItem and filing the bug to Qt. Or... If MenuItem{} on top is a must then make it a parent for the Image{} inside (that I am not sure of). Huh? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251946/qt-qml-menuitem-iconsource-not-show

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Qt QML MenuItem iconSource not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251946/qt-qml-menuitem-iconsource-not-show)

Comment: @AlexanderVX The question is sligltly different - not a problem with icon when using `Acion` in `MenuItem` but the ways of using icon from plugin compiled-in resources. Anyway a gues i find out an answer to my question in [Qt QML MenuItem iconSource not show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42251946/qt-qml-menuitem-iconsource-not-show) - _What you are doing wrong?
Nothing. It's all QT's fault._